# jQuery animate moves window

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the window's small enough (you have to scroll down to see the slider) and you click the grey button on the right of the images, the window jumps up to the top of the screen.

Why is that and how can I stop it?

http://jsfiddle.net/CUFjC/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("div#wiseSlider a.arrow").bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    wiseSlider.shouldMove($(this));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CUFjC/14/

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the "button" is a link and when you click it, you will be redirected to "#".
Try to replace the `<a href="#" class="arrow left">` with `<span class="arrow left"></span>` or any other tag, but not `a`.

Comment: It can be an <a> tag, but just leave the href empty, or make it refer to the object its within, so it doesn't move the screen away from it. For example, <a href="#slider" etc... /> if the animated control was called slider.